# How to make sequelize stop creating automatic tables (SEQUELIZE)

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, orm, sequelize.js

I found out that sequelize is creating tables automatically according to the definition of my model names.

I have the following code:

```
const DataTypes = require("sequelize");
const sequelize = require("../mysql.js");

const Approver = sequelize.define("approver", {
  subordinate_id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
    references: {
      model: "user",
      key: "id",
    },
  },
  leader_id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
    references: {
      model: "user",
      key: "id",
    },
  },
  main_leader_id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
    references: {
      model: "user",
      key: "id",
    },
  },
});

const connect = async () => {
  await Approver.sync();
};

connect();

module.exports = Approver;
```

every time I run the local server, I get the following message in the terminal:

```
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `approvers` (`id` INTEGER NOT NULL auto_increment , `subordinate_id` INTEGER NOT NULL, `leader_id` INTEGER NOT NULL, `main_leader_id` INTEGER NOT NULL, `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`), FOREIGN KEY (`subordinate_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`), FOREIGN KEY (`leader_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`), FOREIGN KEY (`main_leader_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

and I found out that the table creation is generated from the model's define because I put other names in the model and the table created was the same as the one I had named the code.

I don't know why the table that is created is in the plural "approvers" and in the model I put the name "approver" and apparently if I try to put another name the plural doesn't happen as well as the word "approver".

the big problem is that I have migrations and when I run them the table "approver" is created in my database, but when I run the command to start the local server, the sequelize creates one more table. So I end up with 2 tables in the database, "approver" of the migration and "approvers" of the model.

I already tried to put the migration and the model with the plural name "approver" but this causes an error when I try to use the model, the sequelize shows a missing field error when I try to create or update data, it says that the value "updatedAt" is missing, and this only happens because the automatically generated table creates this field, but the funniest thing is that the table was not created in my Dbeaver but the sequelize shows the error of being missing a field, even the model containing the plural name and the migration too...

I would like to get the result that the table is not created with the plural.

does anyone know how to solve this bug?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qE3bl.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems here:

1. An auto-creation of a table according to a model definition
2. Pluralization of a table name while auto-creating it

Solutions:

1. Just remove `sync` call or the whole piece of the following code:

```js
const connect = async () => {
  await Approver.sync();
};

connect();
```

If you use migrations to create the whole structure and to make modifications to it then you **don't** need to use `sync` method of a model or a Sequelize instance.

2. Pluralization of table names can be turned off by indicating 'freezeTableName: true' in the model's options (see [Enforcing table name to be equal to a model name](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-basics/#enforcing-the-table-name-to-be-equal-to-the-model-name) in the official documentation).